communicate click between LWC to FlexCard
I have a LWC embedded in my FlexCard which displays conditionally.
I want the LWC to close when a button on it is clicked.
Here is my LWC code:
import pubsub from 'omnistudio/pubsub';
 
    handleWizardFinish(){
            console.log('Process finished. Emitting event');
 
            let result = pubsub.fire("enrollmentFlexCard", "closeLWC");
           
            console.log(result);
    }

and here is how my event listener is set up:

But nothing happens when I click the button?
Did I configure it incorrectly?
Thanks
Edit: Checking the logs, I do see the Process finished. Emitting event however, the next log just says undefined

Hi, have you checked which instance of Omnistudio you are using? There is both the standard Omnistudio runtime which you've imported here, as well as a managed package runtime. The managed package runtime is the older version, and needs to be imported via vlocity_ins/pubsub as per the Docs here

yes i checked the namespace and its omnistudio/pubsub

I have implemented what you are asking. Here is a snippet of the code I used.
const closeflyout = new CustomEvent('closeflyout',{
bubbles: true
});
this.dispatchEvent(closeflyout);
Here is an image of the way I set up my custom event.

